# How to pack files into one executable file for Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, go, cross-platform

I'm creating an desktop app on Golang with Muon UI (using Ultralight instead of Chromium) and cross-build my app for Linux and Windows. For now the app work fine but it required Ultralight libraries (*.dll for Windows and *.so for Linux). But I wanna distribution my app as single executable file. How I can create two executable files? First file for Linux, it's should include main executable file for Linux and only *.so libraries. And second file should include main executable file for Windows and only *.dll libraries. How I can to do this?
Are there any CLI utils for this? (for using in gitlab CI inside Docker for example) Or maybe I can to do this via Golang (for example using embed package. Can I embedded libraries into exe file, that it is can run)?
Or can I use cgo for link dynamic libs as static into binary file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The honest answer would be: ***"With great difficulty, lots of pain, blood and tears."***

The somewhat longer answer is, that a precompiled DLL/.so may contain slightly more than a mere static library. It it possible to "convert" a DLL/.so into a static library? Somewhat. It boils down to dumping its contents into object files, reverting all the relocation entries, possibly dealing with versioned symbols and weak symbols. No, there are no kitchen sink utilities out there, doing all that for you ***on an executable binary level.***

If you can limit yourself to Linux, you may want to look into [Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/). What this does is wrapping everything up into a sort of "self extracting archive", which upon launch will transparently and invisibly unpack itself into an in-situ temporary mount point (which you won't see from the rest of the system).

Now, one option would be to build all the dependencies of your program yourself, and arranging for those builds to be created as static libraries. In that case you're no longer dealing with DLLs. However some libraries do not want to be built for static linking, so your mileage may vary there.

---

Truth to be told: Why is distributing multiple files any issue at all? On Linux/*BSD you must ship separate icon and `.desktop` files anyway, so that stuff shows up in the Desktop application menus. Yes, it'd be nice if instead of dealing with XDG desktop entry files we had the option to place all of that information into a special – let's call it `.xdgdata` – readonly section, with some well known symbol names, so that we could have truly single file distributable executables.

---

My honest suggestion: Don't sweat about it. Just ship the whole bunch of files and don't worry too much about "how this looks".

Comment: If for Linux not a problem pack all file into snap or flatpak packages, then at least how to make one file for Windows? This question worries me the most.

Comment: Or maybe use Qt for UI instead Ultralight?

Comment: Qt more suitable in my case. https://github.com/therecipe/qt this allow create cross-platform desktop applications and allow deployment as a single file too